# Why are my fish swimming in circles?

Tags: stardew-valley

On my Stardew Valley farm, I have a fish pond containing five ice pips. They've just requested a crystal fruit, which I gave them immediately. After doing so, I checked out the pond to see the new capacity, and noticed that it says the fish a are swimming in circles.

[image: Screenshot of Stardew Valley Ice Pip fish pond, population five out of seven, saying "The fish are swimming in circles"]

It's been a while since I looked at the pond, so I don't know if this status is new or not.

Is it bad news? Is it just because they had a request today? Or maybe even just because it's raining? (It's Saturday 13th Summer.) I also have lobster pond and a sturgeon pond (both at maximum), and they've always been happy.

Comment: It's extra-confusing because fish ponds are square, so surely the fish should be swimming in quadrilaterals of some sort if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This status does not mean anything, it is simply one of the randomly picked phrases that are shown when there is no request that needs to be fulfilled.

Comment: Phew! The status did go back to saying that the fish are happy/thriving/whatever the next day.